# Trasfer all html using Json, browser will be quicker

Tags: html, json, xml, browser

If all Html files are transferred using JSON (no closing Tag), our browser will be quicker. 
how do you guys think?

Comment: We guys think we need some evidence.

Comment: @MrLister http://www.maxondev.com/serialization-performance-comparison-c-net-formats-frameworks-xmldatacontractserializer-xmlserializer-binaryformatter-json-newtonsoft-servicestack-text/

Comment: @MrLister http://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2014/4562/pdf/10.pdf

Comment: What does it matter what we think? Have you done any measurements, and if so, what did you measure and what were the results?

Comment: Not clear what this question means, it reads as you want to make you html into json before sending it but it need to be html to be rendered in the browser? and therefore would then need converting back again

Comment: @MichaelKay Because now all html will be transfered using xml format, if we use json, it would be faster, because we need less data to transfer

Comment: @Dhunt I mean, transfer all website using json, now we use xml format. Because now all html will be transfered using xml format, if we use json, it would be faster, because we need less data to transfer

Comment: So converting html to json sending then json to html before rendering? If so then I would say any very small time saved would then be offset by the extra time taken to convert. Json is useful just now when we replace an xml serializer with json serializer (still has a conversion time) and it is on large collection which mean removing tags and so on makes a bigger difference because there are more of them. An HTML page is generally very small and wouldn't have thought this would make much difference. Correct me if I am talking about the wrong thing.

Comment: Stop speculating and do some research. Start with http://www.balisage.net/Proceedings/vol10/html/Lee01/BalisageVol10-Lee01.html

Comment: You're talking about data, right, from a database, that needs to get displayed? And there is already a JavaScript program on the client side which does the fetching? Not about the structure of the webpages that are XSLT now?

Comment: @Michael Kay very cool answer, thank you.